# Bump System (Show recent thread with reply on top)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

For now I sort all the threads in my forum using this:

```
SELECT * FROM board ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50
```

This shows the newest thread created on the top, but how would I go about showing the thread that has the most recent reply but also showing a new thread on the top?

Example:

> 1. This is a new thread
> 2. This is a old thread
> 3. This is a old thread

To:

> 1. This is a old thread with a new reply
> 2. this is a new thread without replies
> 3. This is a old thread

This is the reply code if thats any help:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO reply (id, name, subject, maintext, ip, date, img)

VALUES

('$idid','$name','$subject','$maintext','$encoded','$date','$image_name')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))

  {

  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());

  }

mysql_query("UPDATE board SET replycount = replycount + 1 WHERE id = $idid");
```

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what you are trying to achieve. Also post all relevant code you have so far.

Comment: I hope you're doing proper escaping on all those variables you're inserting into the query string. if you're not, then go read up about [sql injection](http://bobby-tables.com) before you even TRY to deal with your ordering problem.

Comment: I am, but I'm not showing that part of the code as its not relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to sort by both recent replies and newest threads.  I can't give you exact syntax without more information about your tables, but your query might look something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM board
ORDER BY GREATEST(replyDateTime, creationDateTime)
LIMIT 50;
```

This uses the [`GREATEST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) function to sort each row by either `replyDateTime`, or `creationDateTime`... whichever is more recent.

EDIT:

With your reply information in a separate table, your query could use a left join, and then select the most recent reply for each post in board... and then use `GREATEST` to select either the creation date of the post, or the most recent reply of the post.

```
/* You will need to specify all your columns in board instead of using * */
SELECT b.ID, b.CreationTimeStamp, MAX(r.CreationTimestamp)
FROM 
    board b
    LEFT JOIN replies r ON r.BoardID = b.ID
/* Include all your columns in your select from board here in your group by */
GROUP BY b.ID, b.CreationTimeStamp
ORDER BY GREATEST(b.CreationTimestamp, MAX(r.CreationTimestamp))
LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: I have one table where the replies lies with a timestamp and a id to keep track of to what thread it belongs to, and the thread table has a id and a timestamp. So it would be possible to implement this somehow with that kind of set-up?

Comment: @Nuns531 Yea, let me update my answer to reflect that the info is in two tables...