# How to order by "merged" create_at of both a parent and associated model (Ruby on Rails, SQLite)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, sql-order-by

Here's the problem.

I need to order my threads (topics) by both create_at of threads and replies to threads at the same time (like merge both create_at columns and order by this merged one).

So, it should be ordered by the last post in thread including the thread OP-message itself.

The best solution, I could come with after research and experimentations is:

```
topics.includes(:replies).order('replies.created_at DESC, topics.created_at DESC')
```

But this puts the threads with replies first, the threads without replies then (even if they are created later).

Basically, I need "bump" system like on imageboards. I can refer to this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644548/bump-system-show-recent-thread-with-reply-on-top), I need to do the same but in Rails + SQLite.

Please give any clues. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could enable the `touch` option of the `belongs_to` association:

```ruby
class Reply
  belongs_to :topic, touch: true
end
```

Now every time a reply is created, the `updated_at` attribute of the Topic model will be updated.

Thus you can simply sort by the `updated_at` column of the topics table:

```ruby
topics.order(updated_at: :asc)
```

Comment: Thanks, Fabian, didn't know about that feature. However, it won't probably work in this case, because topics are to be edited (by admins), therefore update update_at, and this should not bump the topic.

Comment: Too bad. You can add a `bumped_at` column to your `Topic` model that you can use for this purpose. You'll need to add a callback to your `Topic` and `Reply` class that takes care of  the `bumped_at` column. I can sketch a simple solution, if you want me to. But your solutions seems perfectly fine as well.

Comment: At the end of the day, I implemented your solution (`bumped_at` that's `touch`ed in controller) since I needed more options for bumping (like `sage` and bump-limit). And of course it's much more cleaner. Thank you for your tips, Fabian, I'll mark your answer as the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

After a session of programming shamanism, I got the solution.

Actually I just took [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10644633/9258716) for SQL/PHP and tranformed it into SQLite/Rails:

```
topics.left_joins(:replies).group('topics.id').order(
          'IFNULL(MAX(replies.created_at), topics.created_at) DESC')
```